# @media queries in a very odd React implementation using .tsx and .ts files

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

I have been working with React for the past two or so years, and with @media queries since the early 2000's. I have just been onboarded onto a new project where they are building React components in a fairly novel way, at least to my experience.

I'll place a snippet below to illustrate what I mean, but essentially they do not use .js and .css files as I usually do, but rather use .tsx and .ts files. They create a component in the .ts file and immediately apply the styling. It looks like this:

//.ts file

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  .second-chart {
    margin-top: 44px;
  }
`;
```

//.tsx file

```
import {Container} from "./styles";
...
<Container>
   <div className="second-chart">
   ...
   </div>
</Container>
```

I perfectly get how this works, and it seems simple enough to use. I am however concerned about how I would write @media queries for this type of implementation? I don't even know what to call it so I might be able to search for suggestions online.

Does anyone know a term I can use for this type of implementation? Or better yet, could someone please let me know how I can write a @media query for it? I was thinking that if I knew how to add a class to the 'styled.div' portion in the .ts file, I could always add my @media queries to a separate .css file.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why can't you use normal scss files with React? And by the way, are you looking for the term css-in-js?

Comment: @AbinThaha This is an existing system that I am onboarding with. I need to follow the same approach as the previous developers on the project, so I can't redo the entire  system to not work like this. Thanks for the term, I'll look into it to see if it gives me any clues.

Comment: @AbinThaha, thank you, the term 'css-in-js' is indeed the correct term, and I believe I have found a solution. WIll post it here is a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as though the project is using [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/). As @phunder has pointed out, you can include all your normal css within the styled element which includes your media queries like so:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  font-size: 16px

  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    font-size: 12px
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Abin Thaha's comment I was able to find the answer to the question. You simply add it to the declaration as a child, like so:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
  display:flex;
  .second-chart {
    margin-top: 44px;
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    .second-chart {
        margin-top: 35px;
    }
  }
`;
```